# Vuetify v-bottom-navigation: Move buttons closer together?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

On some mobile devices (e.g. iPhone 5/SE) the vuetify `v-bottom-navigation` looks as follows:

[image]

To prevent this, I want to move the buttons closer together, so that it looks like on other devices:

[image]

My approach was to pass the `small` prop / class but it didn't work:

```
<v-bottom-navigation>

  <v-btn small>
    <v-icon>mdi-home-outline</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <!-- ... more buttons here ... -->

</v-bottom-navigation>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the padding and min width of the buttons and adjust it to your needs:

```html
<v-bottom-navigation>

  <v-btn class="my-btn" small>
    <v-icon>mdi-home-outline</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <!-- ... more buttons here ... -->

</v-bottom-navigation>

.v-btn.my-btn {
  min-width: 20px !important;
}
```

Also take a look at the component API and [SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-bottom-navigation/#sass-variables)